# Custom post type missing custom fields

Tags: custom-field

The theme I purchased came without custom fields in the post/product editor. It uses a custom post type in its own admin php file. I've managed to add custom fields by pulling the following code out of wordpress core metabox.php file however I'm unsure how to get it to work. Its missing the area where the custom field values should go.

```
<div id="postcustomstuff">
<div id="ajax-response"></div>
<?php
$metadata = has_meta($post->ID);
list_meta($metadata);
meta_form(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: This sounds like it might be a support issue for the theme. Have you contact the vendor?

Comment: You can't simply call in the markup for the fields and expect it to work, there's a bunch of ajax functionality that's tied to the custom fields, replicating that inside some custom administration page isn't going to be a case of just printing out the appropriate HTML. As Mike said, this may really be a question that should be raised with the theme developer(s).

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure I'm not going to get any help out of the developer, his site is down at the moment as well. I was hoping that someone might know an easier way that I could just paste into the function file. I've made my own post type with custom fields however trying to implement it into the theme is going to be a pita.

Answer (score 2):

Is display of the "Custom Fields" metabox enabled for your Custom Post Type's Edit Screen?

To check:

1) Edit (Post Type) Screen
2) Click the "Screen Options" tab in the upper right-hand corner
3) Ensure the "Custom Fields" checkbox is enabled

WordPress 3.1 made some (ahem) *decisions* regarding which metaboxes should display by default on the Edit screens. In some cases, previously displayed metaboxes were changed *not to display* by default.

Answer (score 1):

In your theme files look for the code that registers the custom post type most likely using the register_post_type() function and in its arguments array where it says 'supports' => ...
Add 'custom-fields' to that string.

Comment: The setup file has custom-fields in the register_post_type array the theme doesn't seem to make use of it at all. It has its own processing for fields if that helps. In an admin add product processing file.

Comment: if (!empty($_GET['p'])){
 $post = get_post($_GET['p']);
 if (!empty($post) && $post->post_type != 'product'){
  $error = __('Invalid product ID','re');
 }
 $product['id'] = $post->ID;
 $product['title'] = $post->post_title;
 $product['desc'] = $post->post_content;
 $product['desc'] = $post->post_content;
 $product['status'] = $post->post_status;
 $product['images'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tgt_product_images', true);
 $product['url'] = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'tgt_product_url', true);

Comment: @steen: You can edit your question to include this code. The comments are too small for them.

Comment: well then without seeing the code  its hard to say but maybe you have a remove_meta_box function there to remove the default custom fields metabox.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure support for custom fields is implemented at all? Support of meta for custom post type must be declared in `supports` argument in [`register_post_type()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) or separate  [`add_post_type_support()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support) call.

That would cover WP native edit controls, not sure how (if at all) that applies to custom page of your theme, might be better question for its developer indeed.

Comment: It is in the setup file however it doesn't seem to make use of the support array at all.

Comment: $args = array(
   'labels' => array('Products'),
   'public' => true,
   'publicly_queryable' => true,
   'show_ui' => false, 
   'show_in_menu' => false, 
   'query_var' => true,
   'rewrite' => true, // Permalinks
   'capability_type' => 'post',
   'has_archive' => true, 
   'hierarchical' => false,
   'menu_position' => null,
   'taxonomies' => array('category', 'filter', 'post_tag'),
   'supports' => array('title','editor','author',custom-field','thumbnail','excerpt','comments'),
   //'_edit_link' => 'post.php?post=%d',
  
   ); 
   register_post_type('product', $args);

Comment: @steen: Syntactical error on your supports array. Missing a single quote `'`